FullSimplify returns complex number even though assumptions make it real
EDIT: Maybe the scope of my question is really how to solve in closed-form for the real roots of the cubic, conditional on being in the parameter space where the discriminant is positive.
So I'm solving for some eigenvalues of a square matrix, $A$. Even though I am assuming the discriminant is greater than 0, Mathematica still outputs a complex solution which is undesirable. I do not want to visit the parameter space with complex eigenvalues and want to code to reflect that all formulas result in real numbers. How can I force Mathematica to give me a symbolically real solution. Here is my code, I've omitted the Symbolize[] calls.
A = ( {
   {-Subscript[\[Kappa], g], Subscript[\[Phi], 
    g], -Subscript[\[Phi], g]},
   {Subscript[\[Phi], \[CapitalPi]], -Subscript[\[Kappa], \
\[CapitalPi]], 0},
   {Subscript[\[Zeta], 0, g], Subscript[\[Zeta], 
    0, \[CapitalPi]], -Subscript[\[Kappa], r]}
  } )

cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, \[Lambda]]

\[CapitalDelta] = 
 FullSimplify[Discriminant[cp, \[Lambda]], 
  Assumptions -> {Subscript[\[Kappa], g] > 0, 
    Subscript[\[Kappa], \[CapitalPi]] > 0, Subscript[\[Kappa], r] > 0,
     Subscript[\[Phi], g] > 0}]

eigvalscp = Roots[cp == 0 , \[Lambda]];

Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] = 
 FullSimplify[Last[eigvalscp[[2]]], 
  Assumptions -> {Subscript[\[Kappa], g] > 0, 
    Subscript[\[Kappa], \[CapitalPi]] > 0, Subscript[\[Kappa], r] > 0,
     Subscript[\[Phi], g] > 0, \[CapitalDelta] > 0, 
    Im[Last[eigvalscp[[2]]]] == 0}]

\[CapitalDelta] /. {Subscript[\[Kappa], g] -> 1, 
  Subscript[\[Kappa], \[CapitalPi]] -> 0.5, 
  Subscript[\[Kappa], r] -> 0.25, Subscript[\[Phi], g] -> 0.05, 
  Subscript[\[Phi], \[CapitalPi]] -> 0.1, 
  Subscript[\[Zeta], 0, g] -> 0.1, 
  Subscript[\[Zeta], 0, \[CapitalPi]] -> 1} 
*0.003828 > 0 *

Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] /. {Subscript[\[Kappa], g] -> 1, 
  Subscript[\[Kappa], \[CapitalPi]] -> 0.5, 
  Subscript[\[Kappa], r] -> 0.25, Subscript[\[Phi], g] -> 0.05, 
  Subscript[\[Phi], \[CapitalPi]] -> 0.1, 
  Subscript[\[Zeta], 0, g] -> 0.1, 
  Subscript[\[Zeta], 0, \[CapitalPi]] -> 1}
* -0.2926 + 1.85037*10^-17 I *


eigvalscp[[2]] contains imaginary unit I, but you intentionally select it.

@A.Kato I hadn't realized. Can I tell roots to give me real solutions? Or why wouldn't using FullSimplify assuming discriminant is 0 get rid of the imaginary component?

eigvalscp[[1]] contains no imaginary unit, so I suspect it is a real solution. MMA tries to find all (complex) solutions.

This is true. If the discriminant is less than 0 the second and third roots are imaginary. But I'm assuming the discriminant is greater than 0 so roots 2 and 3 are guaranteed to be real

eigvalscp is computed without using discriminant data, isn't it?

Yes. Do you know of a way to include it? I couldn't figure it out. I assumed FullSimplify would work after I computed eigvalscp.

Just replace eigvalscp[[2]] in your code by eigvalscp[[1]].

I need to solve for all roots. I am diagonolizing a system of ODEs with this information. Thus im trying to limit it to the case where all roots are real and distinct.

I'm sorry I cannot understand your goal. Please wait for someone-else's help.

@A.Kato Thanks!

1.85037*10^-17 I is negligible round-off error. Use exact input if you wish to avoid it.

Also consider this advice, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395, especially point 3.

@MichaelE2 Thank you. This post is very helpful.

Your discriminant is
TeXForm[List@@\[Delta]]/.{\\ \\:> \\ \\ +}

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \kappa _g^4 \left(\kappa _r-\kappa _{\Pi }\right){}^2 \\ +
 \kappa _r^4 \left(4 \phi _g \phi _{\Pi }+\kappa _{\Pi }^2\right) \\ +
 2 \kappa _g^3 \left(-2 \phi _g \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }-\left(\left(\kappa _r-\kappa _{\Pi }\right)
   \left(-\phi _g \left(\zeta _{0,g}+\phi _{\Pi }\right)-\kappa _{\Pi }^2+\kappa
   _r^2\right)\right)\right) \\ +
 -2 \kappa _r^3 \left(\phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \left(\zeta _{0,g}+4 \phi _{\Pi }\right)+2 \phi _g \phi
   _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\kappa _{\Pi }^3\right) \\ +
 \kappa _r^2 \left(2 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi }^2 \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right)+6 \phi _g \kappa
   _{\Pi } \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\phi _g^2 \left(-20 \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,g}+\zeta _{0,g}^2-8
   \phi _{\Pi }^2\right)+\kappa _{\Pi }^4\right) \\ +
 2 \phi _g \kappa _r \left(3 \kappa _{\Pi }^2 \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\kappa _{\Pi }^3 \left(4 \zeta
   _{0,g}+\phi _{\Pi }\right)+\phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \left(19 \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,g}+4 \zeta
   _{0,g}^2+4 \phi _{\Pi }^2\right)+9 \phi _g \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi } \left(\zeta _{0,g}+2 \phi
   _{\Pi }\right)\right) \\ +
 \kappa _g^2 \left(2 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi }^2 \left(4 \phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right)+6 \phi _g \kappa
   _{\Pi } \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\phi _g^2 \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right){}^2+\kappa _r^2
   \left(2 \phi _g \left(\phi _{\Pi }-4 \zeta _{0,g}\right)-6 \kappa _{\Pi }^2\right)+2 \kappa _r \left(5
   \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \left(\zeta _{0,g}-\phi _{\Pi }\right)+3 \phi _g \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi
   }+\kappa _{\Pi }^3\right)+\kappa _{\Pi }^4+2 \kappa _{\Pi } \kappa _r^3+\kappa _r^4\right) \\ +
 -2 \kappa _g \left(\phi _g \left(\kappa _{\Pi }^3 \left(\phi _{\Pi }-4 \zeta _{0,g}\right)+\phi _g
   \kappa _{\Pi } \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right) \left(4 \zeta _{0,g}+5 \phi _{\Pi }\right)+3
   \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi } \left(3 \phi _g \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right)-\kappa _{\Pi
   }^2\right)\right)-\kappa _r^3 \left(\phi _g \left(\zeta _{0,g}-4 \phi _{\Pi }\right)+\kappa _{\Pi
   }^2\right)-\kappa _r^2 \left(5 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \left(\zeta _{0,g}+2 \phi _{\Pi }\right)+3 \phi
   _g \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\kappa _{\Pi }^3\right)+\kappa _r \left(5 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi }^2
   \left(2 \zeta _{0,g}+\phi _{\Pi }\right)+12 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }-\phi
   _g^2 \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right) \left(5 \zeta _{0,g}+4 \phi _{\Pi }\right)+\kappa _{\Pi
   }^4\right)+\kappa _{\Pi } \kappa _r^4\right) \\ +
 \phi _g \left(-4 \kappa _{\Pi }^3 \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\phi _g \kappa _{\Pi }^2 \left(-20 \phi
   _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,g}-8 \zeta _{0,g}^2+\phi _{\Pi }^2\right)-18 \phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \phi _{\Pi }
   \zeta _{0,\Pi } \left(2 \zeta _{0,g}+\phi _{\Pi }\right)-4 \kappa _{\Pi }^4 \zeta _{0,g}+\phi _g
   \left(4 \phi _g \left(\phi _{\Pi }-\zeta _{0,g}\right){}^3-27 \phi _{\Pi }^2 \zeta _{0,\Pi
   }^2\right)\right) \\ +
\end{array} $$
It's of course impossible to locate such an expression somewhere in the root expression:
Position[Solve[...,\[Lamba}],\[\CapitalDelta]]

You have to go the way backwards.
Your characteristic polynomial is #
$$-\phi _g \kappa _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,g}-\phi _g \phi _{\Pi } \zeta _{0,\Pi }+\lambda  \left(-\phi _g \zeta _{0,g}-\kappa _g \kappa _{\Pi }+\phi _g \phi _{\Pi }-\kappa _g \kappa _r-\kappa _{\Pi } \kappa _r\right)+\lambda ^2 \left(-\kappa _g-\kappa _{\Pi }-\kappa _r\right)+\phi _g \phi _{\Pi } \kappa _r-\kappa _g \kappa _{\Pi } \kappa _r-\lambda ^3$$
Its simply impossible to generate a set of conditions on the set of six parameters
$$\{g,r,\zeta ,\kappa ,\Pi ,\phi \}$$
to assure a special root to be real.
But we know that a real cubic has one real root and two real or complex conjugate roots. To formulate the positivity condition of the discriminant is useless, simply because Mathematica cannot identify it in the representation in the result.
Isolate the imaginary part of the two possibly non real roots and try to find a Greobner basis in the parameter space for a zero of the imaginary part, where you have the explicit representation of the discriminant. Simply replace it by your symbol $\Delta$, don't give it a value.
Then concentrate to generate a series of inequalities of the parameters by
 Reduce[\[Delta]==0] 

with additional inequalities of ranges taken from the physical models in real numbers.

Thank you for this answer. I found it very insightful. It hadn't occurred to me that  assuming a necessary and sufficient condition for something does not necessarily imply there is enough information for Mathematica to be able to simplify the expression.
